# org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property of bean class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to code a postgresql to cvs batch, but when I run it I get [this exception](https://pastebin.com/T8c31Ewa).

My classes are:

```
public class Salle {

    private Integer idSalle;
    private String type;
    private Boolean archiver;
    private String nom_salle;
    private String remarque;
    private Integer etablissement_id;

    public Integer getIdSalle() {
        return this.idSalle;
    }

    public void setIdSalle(Integer idSalle) {
        this.idSalle = idSalle;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return this.type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Boolean getArchiver() {
        return this.archiver;
    }

    public void setArchiver(Boolean archiver) {
        this.archiver = archiver;
    }

    public String getNom_salle() {
        return this.nom_salle;
    }

    public void setNom_salle(String nom_salle) {
        this.nom_salle = nom_salle;
    }

    public String getRemarque() {
        return this.remarque;
    }

    public void setRemarque(String remarque) {
        this.remarque = remarque;
    }

    public Integer getEtablissement_id() {
        return this.etablissement_id;
    }

    public void setEtablissement_id(Integer etablissement_id) {
        this.etablissement_id = etablissement_id;
    }
}
```

I have getter and setter well defined.

I am using spring-boot v2.1.6.RELEASE spring-batch 4.1.2 .

Comment: Can you try change the return type from Integer to int in case idSalle ?

Comment: sorry is a stupid case sensitive problem, i changed to idSalle in my RowMapper implementation and it work fine, really sorry.

Comment: Please provide the full exception stacktrace inline in your question, don't use external links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error is the camelcase in your property. According to the exception the property is `idsalle` which is resolving to `getIdsalle()` but in your shown class you have `idSalle` with uppercase S and the getter `getIdSalle()`.

regards, WiPu

Comment: yes you are right, it work now.